# How to do rdiff backup restore

Tags: linux, backup, bash, backup-restoration, rdiff-backup

How to do rdiff back restore using program ( perl, bash )

Can i get more informatio about rdiff back restore ?

Answer (score 2):

The [rdiff-backup web site](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html#restore) has an explicit example of restoring files that have been backed up with rdiff-backup.

Comment: thats not working

Comment: Please elaborate on this. where exactly does it fail?